# when trying to run yarn install on botFramework-composer

Tags: chatbot

but I get this error
error @microsoft/bf-orchestrator@4.14.0-rc0: The CPU architecture "arm64" is incompatible with this module

on Apple M1 Pro (macOS ventura version 13.4.1)

and unable to complete the installation